# azerothcore mysql database version doesn't match

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-connector, azerothcore

I successfully followed the instructions at https://www.azerothcore.org/ to install AzerothCore on Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server. I had it running and successfully created an account, logged in, and everything was great. I shut down the server while I was away.

Upon starting the server I get a fatal error:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------#

>> FATAL ERROR

# Location '/home/wowadmin/azerothcore/src/server/database/Database/DatabaseWorkerPool.cpp:79'
# Function 'DatabaseWorkerPool'
# Condition 'isSameClientDB'
# Message 'Used MySQL library version (8.0.33 id 80033) does not match the version id used to compile AzerothCore (id 80032).
Search the wiki for ACE00046 in Common Errors (https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/common-errors#ace00046).'

#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

I looked at the wiki and I'm unable to determine the problem. I even re-compiled, but it won't start. I confirmed the config file points to the correct sql:

```
-- Using mysql-config: /usr/bin/mysql_config
-- Found MySQL library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
-- Found MySQL headers: /usr/include/mysql
-- Found MySQL executable: /usr/bin/mysql
```

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction while I continue to research this.

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake. After recompiling, I missed a step. I didn't actually make the install.

One simple command and about an hour later and it was running smoothly.

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/linux-core-installation: it was this line of code:

```
make install
```